# least square method for finding unknown variables

Tags: python

I need to compute two unknown variable with least square method , I have got the experimental data which are produced ( simiulated ) by a few line of code at first. so at the beginning two variable which are phase and width are known to simulate the data. in the second part these two variable are considered unknown and with the help of data and least squares method I am going to compute them. but there is a problem!. if the phase is between 0 to pi the code gives the right value and when it is between pi to 2*pi wrong value is retuned. I need to compute these two variables for any arbitrary value with high precision that is entered in the first part.
Thanks to those who would help in advance.
this is the code bellow:

```
from numpy import sin,cos,pi,linspace,sqrt,zeros,arccos
from scipy.special import fresnel as f
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares as lst
import numpy as np

# first part to simulate data
m=500
l=632.8e-9
z=.25
a=0.3e-3 
b=6e-3
p=(1.7)*pi  
q=sqrt(2/(l*z))
x=linspace(-b,b,m)
v2=-q*(x-a)
v1=-q*(x+a)
s,c,I=zeros(m),zeros(m),zeros(m)

for i in range(m):
    s[i]=f(v2[i])[0]-f(v1[i])[0]
    c[i]=f(v2[i])[1]-f(v1[i])[1]

for j in range(m):
    I[j]=1+(1-cos(p))*((c[j]**2 +s[j]**2 )-(c[j]+s[j]))+sin(p)*(c[j]-s[j])


# second part to compute a and p
def model(y,x):
    w=sqrt(2/(l*z))
    C=f(w*(y[1]-x))[1]-f(w*(-y[1]-x))[1]
    S=f(w*(y[1]-x))[0]-f(w*(-y[1]-x))[0]
    return 1+(1-cos(y[0])) *(C**2 -C +S**2 -S)+sin(y[0])*(C-S)


def func(y,x,z):
    return (z-model(y,x))


ExI=I
y0=np.array([0.5,50e-6])
reslm = lst(func, y0,method='lm',args=(x, ExI),verbose=2)
print('Real phase and channel width : ',p , a)
print(' lm method ')
print('Estimated phase : ' ,reslm.x[0] if reslm.x[0]>=0 else 2*pi+reslm.x[0])
print('channel width' ,  reslm.x[1])
```